# Will Mongo handle my service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been using MongoDB with `node.js` and `mongoose` library. I decided to start using MongoDB because I found everywhere that it is the best solution for `node.js` applications.

Although the response times of my API are good, I'm unsure that MongoDB will handle it when scaling it.

I've noticed that most of my queries aren't enough to get all the data I need, so I rely on creating several queries and using some javascript map/reduce functions (that is what I'm afraid of).

Look at this example:

```
        User
        .find({
            idol : true
        })
        .sort({
            'metas.followers' : -1
        })
        .select('-password -__v -posts -email')
        .skip(offset)
        .limit(30)
        .exec(function(err, retData)
        {
            promisedIdols = retData.map(function(idol)
            {
                return idol.withStatistics(Post, Follow, req.user);
            });

            idols = [];

            if(promisedIdols.length == 0)
            {
                callback();
            }

            for(var i=0; i<promisedIdols.length; i++)
            {
                promisedIdols[i].delegate(function(result)
                {
                    idols.push(result);

                    if(idols.length == promisedIdols.length)
                    {
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

I've used a `map` to gather an array of `promises` that will be resolved after running the following code:

```
var obj = this.toObject();
var deferred = new Promise();

Post
.find({ idol : obj._id })
.lean()
.exec(function(err, posts)
{
    var postViews = 0;
    var postLikes = 0;
    var postShares = 0;

    posts.reduce(function(prev, next)
    {
        postViews += next.views.length;
        postLikes += next.likes.length;
        postShares += next.shares.length;
    }, 0);

    obj.metas.postViews = postViews;
    obj.metas.postLikes = postLikes;
    obj.metas.postShares = postShares;
    obj.metas.postCount = posts.length;

    Subscription
    .count({ idol : obj._id }, function(err, count)
    {
        obj.metas.subscribers = count;

        deferred.deliver(obj);
    });
});
```

that uses a `reduce` function.

I can't see this code working well on big scale. Maybe should I restructure my database? Maybe should I change my database system? Maybe I'm using MongoDB wrongly?

Experts?

Thanks.

Comment: Its been my discovery that using native array functions will cause problems as your database increases.  One solution (which I just underwent) is to use the async module. async.map / async.reduce can give you exactly what you want, but in a non-blocking way.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper yes, but as you can see, I'm using promises, so I need to wait for the result anyway (and we all know that javascript map/reduce are really slow).

Answer (score 1):

Mongo can handle a lot, if you setup a good data model. There are a few things to keep in mind when you want to scale.

Try to avoid normalizing the data much and split it into different collections.
Data duplication is (sometimes, when used wisely) your friend, it will help you make simpler queries, populate right away. Yeah, that may mean that when you're updating data, you'll have to update in two places, but Mongo is ok with a lot of writes if you do it asynchronously (promises or not).

To your specific query, I don't see the full data model, but maybe you can use aggregation framework. That pipeline is native (C++, as opossed to mapReduce JavaScript) and will work really really fast.

Something like:

```
db.post.aggregate(
  // First $match to reduce the dataset
  {
    $match: {idol : obj._id}
  },
  // then group and aggregate your data
  {
    $group: {
        _id: '$idol',  // group by that idol thing
        postViews: {$sum: '$postViews'},
        postLikes: {$sum: '$postLikes'}
    },
  },
  // Then use project to arrange the result the way you like it
  {
    $project: {
        _id: false, //or true if you need it
        metas: {
          postViews: '$postViews'
        },
        likeCountOfPosts: '$postLikes', // that's how you'd rename
        whatIsIt: {$literal: 'a great post'}
    }
  }
);
```

You can also do a lot of conditional, groupings, sortings, winding and unwinding, mixing and shuffling the pipeline.

It's much much faster then Mongo mapReduce.

Comment: thanks! It still can't replace map/reduce in some cases though. I'm using your suggestion of data duplication, it reduce some queries!